# Area 51 still reports that Web applications is in beta

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

Web applications [just graduated](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) from beta and area51 still reports it in beta
 See [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications)

The counter is even broken:

[image]

No, I will not give you a break, you had a *a lot* of time to test this scenario. (yes, the harsh tone in this sentence is a joke)

Comment: Someone had to report it

Comment: Goodbye public beta, hello public gamma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now, I'd leave it in the homepage though (now it's removed) and I'd add a link to the live site (<strike>I don't see it currently, see screenshot below</strike> -- ah, the logo is the link)

Also, I'd add a new tab ;)
[image]